# LND not showing URI

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

LND seems to be running ok, i opened several channels and paid for a couple of things already, first couple of days  i could see all the info regarding my node but since yesterday my uri just disappeared, i know this not big deal since i can always find the external ip of my pi but i want my node to be easily discovered and well connected.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? Where could you see all your data? The URI consists of your node_ID, IP and port and in particular the node_id should not have changed.

Comment: which is the output of lncli getinfo are you using lncli commandline?